How can I display each `dt` and `dd` pair in a single column using CSS Grid without modifying the HTML structure?
I have the following HTML, and I want each pair of dt and dd elements to be displayed in a single column, resulting in two columns per row. However, when using CSS Grid, it treats each dt and dd as separate columns.
Here's the HTML:


/* First attempt */
dl {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-areas: "
    mm bb
";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

dt, dd {grid-area: bb;}
 dt:nth-of-type(2n) {
background:red;
   grid-area: mm;
        }

        dt:nth-of-type(2n) + dd {
          background:red;   grid-area: mm;
        }

/*dt:has(+ dd):nth-child(even), dt + dd {
  border:1px solid blue;
}*/
<dl>
    <dt>Term 1</dt>
    <dd>Definition 1</dd>
    <dt>Term 2</dt>
    <dd>Definition 2</dd>
    <dt>Term 3</dt>
    <dd>Definition 3</dd>
    <dt>Term 4</dt>
    <dd>Definition 4</dd>
</dl>



My goal is to achieve this layout:
Term 1: Definition 1        | Term 2: Definition 2
Term 3: Definition 3        | Term 4: Definition 4

I cannot modify the HTML structure. I tried the following CSS, but it didn't work as expected.
And here's another attempt that is closer to what I want but still not right:
dl {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
            gap: 20px;
        }

        dt, dd {
            margin: 0;
        }

        dt:nth-of-type(odd),
        dd:nth-of-type(odd) {
            grid-column: 1;
        }

        dt:nth-of-type(even),
        dd:nth-of-type(even) {
            grid-column: 2;
        }

        dt {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        dd {
/*            margin-left: 20px;*/
        }

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this to get the desired layout with each dt and dd pair in a single column?
CodePen Example:
https://codepen.io/amit-cohen-the-selector/pen/jOoMGbV?editors=1100

you will need 4 columns not two

I consider Term 1: Definition 1 to be one column. I mean if I do repeat(4, 1fr) then I will have 4 columns. the gap between each of them can be grow. and I expect to the gap between col-2 and col-3 to be grow (col-1: col-2.    col-3: col-4).
So in grid can I do it?

As mentioned in the comments by @TemaniAfif you need 4 columns not 2


* {
  margin: 0;
}

dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr min-content 1fr;
  column-gap: 1em;
}

dt,
dd {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<dl>
  <dt>Term 1</dt>
  <dd>Definition 1</dd>
  <dt>Term 2</dt>
  <dd>Definition 2</dd>
  <dt>Term 3</dt>
  <dd>Definition 3</dd>
  <dt>Term 4</dt>
  <dd>Definition 4</dd>
</dl>




I consider Term 1: Definition 1 to be one column. I mean if I do repeat(4, 1fr) then I will have 4 columns. the gap between each of them can be grow. and I expect to the gap between col-2 and col-3 to be grow (col-1: col-2.    col-3: col-4).
So in grid can I do it?

If you look in your browser devtools at the actual styles being applied you may see margins. Set dt and dl margin to 0. And also remove the gap setting. You should see the dl and dt right next to each other (you'll probably want to add a bit of space with a margin setting!).
